Query issues when I use SUM and group records in SQL Server
I have the following query in SQL Server where I am trying to sum the pay time of some records that I group by certain columns. However, the result shows 2 records that should be one.
Here's the query:
SELECT 
    ISNULL(E.EMPID,0) "EMPID", SUM(T.PAYTIME) "PAYTIME", 
    PC.PAYTRANSCODEIDST, PC.PAYTRANSCODEIDOT, 
    T.DispatchDate, ISNULL(CostCenterID, '10109') "CostCenterID"
FROM
    TimeRecord T, Employee E, Paycode PC, EmpType ET 
WHERE 
    E.EmpId = T.EmpId 
    AND PC.Paycode = T.Paycode 
    AND ET.EMPID = T.EMPID 
    AND ((ET.STARTDATE <= '2024-09-29') 
    AND ((ET.ENDDATE IS NULL) or (ET.ENDDATE >= '2024-09-29'))) 
    AND E.EMPID = 3129 
    AND DISPATCHDATE = '2024-09-27'
GROUP BY  
    E.EMPID, CostCenterID, PC.PAYTRANSCODEIDST, 
    PC.PAYTRANSCODEIDOT, T.DISPATCHDATE
ORDER BY  
    E.EmpId, CostCenterID, PC.PayTransCodeIDST, 
    PC.PayTransCodeIDOT, T.DispatchDate

And here are the results:

As you can see, the first 2 records should be one with a bigger pay time. I also tried to use INNER JOIN, ISNULL and also COALESCE for the PAYTRANS... columns, but it didn't work. If I remove the 2 PAYTRANS... columns from GROUP BY and SELECT, it works fine, but I need them. These 2 may also have NULL values in the database but I'm not sure this is what's causing the issue.
This is the result of the query without the GROUP BY:

Thank you.

For starters, update to contemporary JOIN syntax that's been around for 20+ years. Next, do you have a one-to-many join issue here? Sample data would help.

I'm not saying JOIN will fix the query, but it certainly updates the code to the 21st century. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

I changed the original message and put also the result of the query without the GROUP BY.

For one, the query is really hard to read. To demonstrate, why are you adding unnecessary "DOUBLE" "QUOTES" "AROUND" "EVERY" "ALIAS"? Next, you have an expression in SELECT: ISNULL(CostCenterID, '10109'). But in the GROUP BY it is just CostCenterID. You need to group by the same expression.

In fact I bet that's the problem - one of the first two rows actually has a CostCenterID of NULL. Try removing that expression from the second query, because currently it's making it look like that value is present.

Do the ISNULL stuff in a derived table (FROM clause subquery) before you GROUP BY.

Thank you, Aaron. This solved the problem. I put the ISNULL(CostCenterID, '10109') in GROUP BY and now it returns 2 records, as it should.

Or change your alias to something that also isn't a column name.

@Isolated GROUP BY still couldn't reference an alias, so the expression has to be repeated no matter what alias you use (unless you hide it away in a subquery or CTE first, like jarlh suggested).

@AaronBertrand Ah, that's right. Cannot use alias in sql server group by. Have been using mainly postgres lately.

When you apply expressions to columns in the SELECT list, you must use the same expressions in the GROUP BY. You have ISNULL(CostCenterID, '10109') in the SELECT, but in the GROUP BY it is just CostCenterID. You can solve this by repeating the ISNULL expression in the GROUP BY:
SELECT 
    ISNULL(E.EMPID,0) AS EMPID,
    SUM(T.PAYTIME)    AS PAYTIME, 
    PC.PAYTRANSCODEIDST, 
    PC.PAYTRANSCODEIDOT, 
    T.DISPATCHDATE, 
    ISNULL(CostCenterID, '10109') AS CostCenterID
FROM
    TimeRecord AS T
    INNER JOIN Employee AS E
      ON E.EmpId = T.EmpId 
    INNER JOIN Paycode AS PC
      ON PC.Paycode = T.Paycode 
    INNER JOIN EmpType AS ET 
      ON ET.EMPID = T.EMPID 
WHERE 
    AND ((ET.STARTDATE <= '2024-09-29') 
    AND ((ET.ENDDATE IS NULL) or (ET.ENDDATE >= '2024-09-29'))) 
    AND E.EMPID = 3129 
    AND T.DISPATCHDATE = '2024-09-27'
GROUP BY  
    E.EMPID, ISNULL(CostCenterID, '10109'), PC.PAYTRANSCODEIDST, 
    PC.PAYTRANSCODEIDOT, T.DISPATCHDATE
ORDER BY  
    E.EMPID, CostCenterID, PC.PAYTRANSCODEIDST, 
    PC.PAYTRANSCODEIDOT, T.DISPATCHDATE;

Or, as @jarlh suggested, calculating that separately - even though it leads to bulkier code. I generally prefer CTEs for this:
; /* for protection from prior statements */
WITH src AS
(
  SELECT 
    ISNULL(E.EMPID,0) AS EMPID,
    PC.PAYTRANSCODEIDST, 
    PC.PAYTRANSCODEIDOT, 
    T.DISPATCHDATE, 
    ISNULL(CostCenterID, '10109') AS CostCenterID
  FROM
    TimeRecord AS T
    INNER JOIN Employee AS E
      ON E.EmpId = T.EmpId 
    INNER JOIN Paycode AS PC
      ON PC.Paycode = T.Paycode 
    INNER JOIN EmpType AS ET 
      ON ET.EMPID = T.EMPID 
  WHERE 
    AND ((ET.STARTDATE <= '2024-09-29') 
    AND ((ET.ENDDATE IS NULL) or (ET.ENDDATE >= '2024-09-29'))) 
    AND E.EMPID = 3129 
    AND T.DISPATCHDATE = '2024-09-27'
)
SELECT 
  EMPID, 
  SUM(T.PAYTIME) AS PAYTIME,
  PAYTRANSCODEIDST,
  PAYTRANSCODEIDOT,
  DISPATCHDATE,
  CostCenterID 
FROM src
GROUP BY  
    EMPID, CostCenterID, PAYTRANSCODEIDST, 
    PAYTRANSCODEIDOT, DISPATCHDATE
ORDER BY  
    EMPID, CostCenterID, PAYTRANSCODEIDST, 
    PAYTRANSCODEIDOT, DISPATCHDATE;

But you could also use a subquery:
SELECT 
  EMPID, 
  SUM(T.PAYTIME) AS PAYTIME,
  PAYTRANSCODEIDST,
  PAYTRANSCODEIDOT,
  DISPATCHDATE,
  CostCenterID 
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    ISNULL(E.EMPID,0) AS EMPID,
    PC.PAYTRANSCODEIDST, 
    PC.PAYTRANSCODEIDOT, 
    T.DISPATCHDATE, 
    ISNULL(CostCenterID, '10109') AS CostCenterID
  FROM
    TimeRecord AS T
    INNER JOIN Employee AS E
      ON E.EmpId = T.EmpId 
    INNER JOIN Paycode AS PC
      ON PC.Paycode = T.Paycode 
    INNER JOIN EmpType AS ET 
      ON ET.EMPID = T.EMPID 
  WHERE 
    AND ((ET.STARTDATE <= '2024-09-29') 
    AND ((ET.ENDDATE IS NULL) or (ET.ENDDATE >= '2024-09-29'))) 
    AND E.EMPID = 3129 
    AND T.DISPATCHDATE = '2024-09-27'
) AS src
GROUP BY  
    EMPID, CostCenterID, PAYTRANSCODEIDST, 
    PAYTRANSCODEIDOT, DISPATCHDATE
ORDER BY  
    EMPID, CostCenterID, PAYTRANSCODEIDST, 
    PAYTRANSCODEIDOT, DISPATCHDATE;

I also took the liberty of converting your ancient join syntax to something more modern, making your columns match case everywhere and properly reference their source table, and "GETTING" "RID" "OF" "ALL" "THOSE" "DOUBLE" "QUOTES"... future maintainers of your code may want to thank me later.
